# JS hasAttribute with data attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a native way, no jQuery, to check if a dom element has the attribute with the selected value. For example:

```
//assume doc has
data-mod="do" defined
```

This will be true:

`document.hasAttribute('data-mod');`

but this will be false:

`document.hasAttribute('data-mod="do"')`

Is there any way to natively check for a data attribute on a DOM element with the value?

Comment: `document` doesn't have attributes. Do you mean an element in the document, or a specific element has an attribute?

Comment: Make your question clearer.

Comment: _"Is there a native way, no JQuery,"_ Why do you have `jquery` tag at Question ?

Answer (score 16):

You have to access the attribute's value via [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) and compare it to your expected string:

```
if (node.getAttribute('data-mod') === 'do') {
    ...
}
```

For modern browsers you can use [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches):

```
if (node.matches('[data-mod="do"]')) {
    ...
}
```

… or for `[data-*]` attributes you can use [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset):

```
if (node.dataset.mod === 'do') {
    ...
}
```

Comment: matches worked for my use case. What are the implications/ways to support older browsers? if i remember some defined it under different names like msMatchesSelctor() right?

Comment: For the most up-to-date compatibility information, I recommend consulting [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=matches), which shows that you'd need to use `msMatchesSelector` as a fallback to have IE9+ support.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it properly with [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset),

```
if (elementNode.dataset['mod'] == 'do') {
    //your code goes here.
}
```

By using `dataset` you can access the data-attributes of an element easily.

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer. I do not know what the data attribute or the value will be within the function because it can change

Comment: @TDmoneybanks So you will have only this `'data-mod="do"'`  during the execution?

Comment: The function will take in a selector param. its contents could be any valid selector including any data-*="" I need to be able to see if the element has that selector.

Comment: @TDmoneybanks You can go with `element.matches(selector)` as suggested by zzzzBov for your case. But careful while using it as it is being supported by recent browsers only. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches

Comment: Yea i noticed that will match my use case best. Do you know what kind of support for ie 10+? I saw they just define them under different names so if i checked for all the possible names (mozMatchesSelector, webkitMatchesSelector, etc) would I be fine support wise?

Comment: @guest27314 We arent discussing element.dataset but thank you

Comment: Can also be written in dot notation like so: `element.dataset.mod === 'do'`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, here it goes:

```
var selector = document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0]; //Example of an h1
if (selector.getAttribute('data-mod') == "do"){
  //Do your logic
}
```

Comment: `TypeError: document.getAttribute is not a function`

Comment: sorry, document won't have attribute, you have to select a valid selector

Comment: Thank's, sure it works fine. `console.log(document.querySelector('#input-number').getAttribute('type')=='number');`

Answer (score 0):

This may work...

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll('[data-mod="do"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Element.attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes)

```js
function data(el, dataName, dataValue) {
  for (var i = 0; i < el.attributes.length; i++) {
    if (/^(data)(?=-\w+|=[^=]*$|=$|$)/g.test(el.attributes[i].name)) {
      if (dataName && el.attributes[i].name === "data-" + dataName) {
        if (dataName && dataValue 
            && el.attributes[i].name === "data-" + dataName
            && el.attributes[i].value === dataValue) {
          return true
        }
        return true
      } else {
        return true
      }
    }
  }
  return false
}

var elems = document.querySelectorAll("div");

for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  console.log(data(elems[i]))
}

var _name = "prop", _value = "123";

console.log("element #"
            + elems[1].id 
            +" has `data-*` attribute name:"
            +_name
            +", value:"+_value
            , data(elems[1], _name, _value))
```

```html
<div data="abc">abc</div>
<div id="prop" data-prop="123">123</div>
<div>no data</div>
```