# Vanilla Javascript: Find a data attribute of the same name as an element given its id

Tags: javascript, dom, custom-data-attribute

Is it possible to find an element that has a data attribute with the same name of an element's id in the DOM? (Is it a bad practice to give a data attribute the same value as an id?)

Example syntax:

**HTML:**

```
<li id="tab-1"></li>
<p data-tab="tab-1">Content 1</p>
```

Would be curious as to how to accomplish this in Vanilla Javascript. Thank you ☺

*Edit*: I am hoping to make my code so that if I have the ID of the element, I can just look for a data attribute of the same value if I don't have it off the top of my head.

Comment: `querySelector`

Comment: *"is it bad practice"* ... not at all if there is a close relationship between the two. Not entirely clear what you are exactly asking though. What use case are you wanting for *"find same as"*?

Comment: _"Edit: I am hoping to make my code so that if I have the ID of the element, I can just look for a data attribute of the same value if I don't have it off the top of my head."_ You would need the specific `.name` of the `data-*` attribute. `css` selectors do not provide a means to select elements by value of attribute alone.

Comment: _"Is it possible to find an element that has a data attribute with the same name of an element's id"_ The `data-*` attribute does not have `.name` property that is equal to `.id` of element at Question.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can do that.
Here's how you do it:

```js
var usingId = document.querySelector('#tab-1');
var usingDt = document.querySelector('[data-tab="tab-1"]');
console.log(usingId);
console.log(usingDt);
```

```html
<li id="tab-1">Tab</li>
<p data-tab="tab-1">P Tab</p>
```

*Is it a bad practice?*.**Nope**

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to select an element having an unknown `html5` `data-*` attribute using the `.id` string property from a different element, you can query all elements in `document`, check the `.name` and `.value` of each elements' `.attributes`, if `.value` of attribute is equal to `.id` of element which provides `.id` and `.name` of the `.attribute` property is not `"id"`, the element is matched using attribute equals selector at `.querySelector()`

```html
<li id="tab-1"></li>
<p data-tab="tab-1">Content 1</p>
<script>
let id = document.getElementById("tab-1").id;
for (let el of document.querySelectorAll("*")) {
  for (let {name, value} of el.attributes) {  
  if (value === id && name !== "id") {
     document.querySelector(`[${name}="${id}"]`)
     .style.color = "green";
     break;
  }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `let id = document.getElementById("tab-1").id;` this made my day. Thanks. (you could also do `let id = document.getElementById("tab-1").id.split('').join('').replace(/a/g, 'a');`)

Comment: @Kaiido Or `let {id} = document.getElementById("tab-1")`. Was only trying to answer Question as interpreted. That is, query `document` for element using only `.id` to match value of `data-*` attribute.

Comment: @Kaiido As interpreted the Question, the `.name` of the `data-*` attribute was not provided, onlt the `.value` being same as `.id` of a different element. `css` selectors do not select an element by value of attribute alone. Though it can be done by composing a function to do so.

Comment: Ok, css selectors are not the way then, but still this `let id= ...` is completely useless and funny. And instead of looping like that over all elements of quesrySelctorAll, you should use a DOMTreeWalker, it's way more efficient, and only elements can have attributes.

Comment: @Kaiido Enlivening to be aware approach provided you with humor. Have not tried `DomTreeWalker`; perhaps post an Answer as to your interpreation of Question and decided approach?

Comment: TreeWalker is not the best either for this use case, but you should definitely give it a try. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker

Answer (score 0):

If the requisite is to not know the name of the `attribute` which value is the string you are looking for, then you can create an [XPath query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate), which will return you all the elements having an attribute with such value :

`//*[@*='value']`

unwrapped :

```
'//' + // from root to anywhere in the tree
   '*' + // any kind of node
     '[@*' + // with any attribute
         ' = "value"' // which value is 'value'
                      ']'
```

```js
var valueToFind = 'find-me';
var query = document.evaluate(`//*[@*='${valueToFind}']`, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
var elements = [], el;
while(el = query.iterateNext()){
  // in your case you will filter it to not be the original node 
  // if(el !== original)
  elements.push(el);
  }
console.log(elements);
```

```html
<div data-id="find-me"></div>
<div data-id="do-not-find-me"></div>
<div class="find-me"></div>
<div class="do-not-find-me"></div>
<div style="find-me"></div>
<div id="find-me"></div>
```

And if the goal is to get only the elements with `data-*` attributes with such value, then the query is a bit more long :

`//*[@*[starts-with(name(), 'data-')] = '${valueToFind}']`

unwrapped :

```
 '//' + // from root to anywhere in the tree
  '*' + // any kind of node
   '[@*' + // with any attribute
      '[starts-with(name(), "data-")]' + // which starts with "data-"
         ' = "value"' // and which value is 'value'
           ']'
```

```js
var valueToFind = 'find-me';
var query = document.evaluate(`//*[@*[starts-with(name(), 'data-')] = '${valueToFind}']`, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
var elements = [], el;
  
while(el = query.iterateNext()){
  elements.push(el);
  }
console.log(elements);
```

```html
<div data-id="find-me"></div>
<div data-foo="find-me"></div>
<div data-id="do-not-find-me"></div>
<div class="find-me"></div>
<div class="do-not-find-me"></div>
<div style="find-me"></div>
<div id="find-me"></div>
```

Comment: OP is specifically trying to select element having `data-*` attribute having value equal to a different element `.id`. Is `@*` a wildcard? if yes, how to adjust to match only element having `data-*` attribute?

Comment: @guest271314 there is no way I know of to make partially *wildcarded* values, so you'd have to filter it in the while loop : you just have to check for `if([].some.call(el.attributes, a=>{return a.nodeName.indexOf('data-') === 0 && a.nodeValue === "value";}));` You will already have filtered a **huge** part of the document's nodes.

Comment: Why do you not perform the task at Answer? Granted, Question is not entirely clear as to "Is it possible to find an element that has a data attribute with the same `.name` of an element's id" as the `data-*` attribute is `"data-tab"`, not `"data-tab-1"`. Perhaps OP means having the same `data-*` value as a different elements' `.id` value?

Comment: @guest271314, added a new snippet with the filtering, I have to admit I'm confused too as to what is the real requirement.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35806427/js-hasattribute-with-data-attribute-value/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40215773/jquery-select-data-attributes-with-common-keyword/

Comment: @guest271314 actually there is a starts-with XPath function... I didn't know ;-) Answered the second link too, but the first one is a bit unrelated and the `dataset` method is probably cleaner.